# Will I have to reconnect my Xbox one if I do a factory reset?

Tags: xbox-one

The login process to my wifi hotspot is just too complicated, I won't go into details, but it doesn't stop at just typing a password. I don't want to do that, but there are just too many little problems with my console.

Comment: Are you factory resetting your WiFi or Xbox?

Comment: It's my Xbox, not internet.

Answer (score 1):

I want to say yes:

http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/console/reset-console-to-factory-defaults

> Warning Resetting your console to its factory defaults erases all
>   accounts, saved games, **settings**, and home Xbox associations. Anything
>   not synchronized with Xbox Live will be lost. Your console syncs with
>   Xbox Live automatically when it’s connected with the service, so if
>   you've been offline for a while, you'll need to connect to Xbox Live
>   before taking these steps.

Your wifi information will be saved in the settings that will get wiped.

You could try just "Reset and keep my games & apps", that may do the same thing though the page does not specify.